# Make paragraph editable

Tags: jquery

I want to create paragraph editable onclick. I done paragraph editable but only one problem is when i click the out side the text area it become paragraph that is correct but i second time click on paragraph it not work.
I'm really sorry for my english.
Thanks lots for help me.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnalucky/ddsrjppb/1/)

HTML:

```
<p id="about">This is paragraph</p>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        function paraClicked() {
        var aboutText = $('#about').html();
        var editableText = $('<textarea />').css({'width': '100%', 'font-size': '20px'});
        editableText.val(aboutText);
        $('#about').replaceWith(editableText);
        editableText.focus();
        editableText.blur(editableTextBlured);
    }
    function editableTextBlured() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        viewavleText = $('<p>');
        viewavleText.html(text);
        $(this).replaceWith(viewavleText);
        $(viewavleText).click(paraClicked);
    }
    $('#about').click(paraClicked);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didnt specify the id after you changed it back to a pragraph.
Change this line

```
viewavleText = $('<p>');
```

To this

```
viewavleText = $('<p id="about">');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just one small change is needed, you need to keep paragraph id.

```
viewavleText = $('<p id="about">');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddsrjppb/2/